# When creating a new account, uploaded profile picture is lost

Tags: bug, registration, avatar

I created a [sock puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16115299/sloshy) account just now, and noticed that the image I selected when it first signed me up was misplaced after the signup process was complete.

From memory, after I clicked the verification link in the email I got, it showed me a form where I could fill in information about myself, and change my avatar.  Only when I completed the form, there was no trace of the avatar picture I had uploaded, and it was back to the default Gravatar icon it had generated for me, and I had to go into the "edit profile" page to upload my preferred picture again.

This is particularly pesky when you spent some time on finding a good image in a search engine, but closed the image search after you found one.

A good temporary workaround would be to not even show the gravatar at this point in the registration process, if there really is nothing I can do to change it.

Comment: "This is particularly pesky when you spent some time on finding a good image in a search engine, but closed the image search after you found one." - it should still be in your browser cache if you can locate it on your drive :)

Comment: Obviously, I would also have it in my browser history if I didn't use a private window or cleared cache. Still, it's a hassle, and in some minor sense data loss. In the worst case, maybe you composed a nice picture on a loaner device which had to be returned and wiped? Again, don't offer the option when it doesn't work would be a quite robust and simple workaround.